# VS Code add library dependencies?

Tags: c++, dependencies, visual-studio-code, lib

I want to add library dependencies to my project without having to copy and paste them to `MinGW` folders. Is there some way to do this through `VS Code` instead? Pretty much something similar to how `Visual Studio` works with the include paths.

NOTE: my configuration compiles and works perfectly up until you try to add external dependencies.

c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "/usr/include",
                "/usr/local/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "/usr/include",
                    "/usr/local/include"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "/usr/include",
                "/usr/local/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "/usr/include",
                    "/usr/local/include"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.10.25017/include/*",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.15063.0/um",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.15063.0/ucrt",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.15063.0/shared",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.15063.0/winrt",
                "${workspaceRoot}/Dep/include/*",
                "${workspaceRoot}/Dep/lib/glew32.lib"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.10.25017/include/*",
                    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.15063.0/um",
                    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.15063.0/ucrt",
                    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.15063.0/shared",
                    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.15063.0/winrt"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "command": "g++",
    "type": "shell",
    "presentation": {
        "echo": true,
        "reveal": "always",
        "focus": false,
        "panel": "shared"
    },
    "tasks": [
      {
          "taskName": "Build",
          "suppressTaskName": true,
          "windows": {
                "args": [
                    "-g",
                    "--std=c++11",
                    "main.cpp",
                    "-o", "Builds/Win/engine",
                    "glew32.lib",
                    // LIB ARGS
                    "-lopengl32",
                    "-lglu32",
                    //"-lmingw32",
                    "-lglew32"
                ]
            }
        }  
    ]
}
```

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C++ Launch",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/Builds/Win/engine.exe",
            "preLaunchTask": "Build",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "windows": {
                "program": "${workspaceRoot}/Builds/Win/engine.exe"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: some questions for you: do you have any experience with c++ package/dependency managers like vcpkg or conan (tools designed for fetching and managing dependencies)? If not, are you interested in learning them? Similar questions about CMake: any experience? any interest in learning it? They are very commonly used in industry, and helpful for larger projects.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this because the build related dependency is handled by Makefile or CMakeLists.txt

The "includePath" added in c_cpp_properties.json are used for lint or IntelliSense, nothing about the build.

You don't have to copy dependencies into MinGW folders. All you have to do is add you include directory and library to your build system, eg: Makefile.